# Cannot move file to git share

Tags: git

I am on windows 8 and typing following command to move nano to my git share folder

```
$ mv nano C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share
sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Please guide me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some escaping, try:

```
$ mv nano C:\\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\Git\\share
```

Comment: mv: cannot move `nano' to `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\share/nano'